# How to split Series data into two parts

Tags: python-2.7

I have the series data like this:

> Data={"BotBuilder.Data.SessionState":{"callstack":[{"id":"*:Experience","state":{"BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep":0}}],"lastAccess":1538138334991,"version":0}};IsCompressed=False

I want to split this into two parts:

Part1: Data

> {"BotBuilder.Data.SessionState":{"callstack":[{"id":"*:Experience","state":{"BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep":0}}],"lastAccess":1538138334991,"version":0}}

Part2: IsCompressed

> False

Comment: Is your input (`Data=...`) a string or your python code?

Comment: i have "values" column which is series type. in values column , there is two type of records. One is 'Data' and second one is 'IsCompressed'. i have to split 'values' into two new columns as 'Data' & 'IsCompressed'.

Comment: u'values': u'Data={"BotBuilder.Data.SessionState":{"callstack":[{"id":"*:Experience","state":{"BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep":0}}],"lastAccess":1538138334991,"version":0}};IsCompressed=False;'

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm trying this code -

df[['Data', 'IsCompressed']] = df['values'].str.split(";", expand=True)